# How to Create a custom Docker image for Node.js and Selenium-Webdriver?

Tags: node.js, docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I'm trying to have my automation project running in Jenkins, but facing issues with the Docker images downloaded from the Internet. Also facing issues with Linux agent compatibility with my Windows environment.

I downloaded Google Chrome/Chromedriver manually in the build once it runs, but still not able to find the driver.

For this reason, I'm considering creating a custom Docker image that has both Node.js and Selenium Webdriver.

How would I do this?

And can I run in Jenkins?

I'm new to Docker so not sure how and where to start ...

```js
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:19'
            registryUrl 'URL'
            registryCredentialsId '123'
            args '-v usr/local/bin:/tmp/bin'
            args '-u root:root'
        }
    }
    environment {
        npm_config_cache='npm-cache'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '123456', url: 'git repo'
            }
        }
        // stage('lockfileversion change') {
        //     steps {
        //         script {
        //             def packageJson = readFile('package-lock.json').trim()
        //             packageJson = packageJson.replaceAll(/"lockfileVersion":\s*3/, '"lockfileVersion":1')
        //             writeFile file: 'package-lock.json', text: packageJson
        //         }
        //     }
        // }
        stage('Create Folder and Download Binaries') {
            steps {
                script {

                    
                    sh 'echo "Trying to install"'
                    
                    //Download driver
                    sh '''#!/bin/sh
                    echo 'TRYING INSTALL'
                    mkdir -p tmp/bin
                    wget -O tmp/bin/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
                    dpkg -c tmp/bin/chrome.deb
                    version=$(curl -s http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE);
                    echo 'Currently LATEST_RELEASE:' $version;
                    echo 'TRYING INSTALL'
                    wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip
                    echo 'TRYING INSTALL'
                    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /tmp/bin
                    chmod +x chromedriver
                    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
                    export PATH=/tmp/bin/google:$PATH
                    echo 'TRYING INSTALL'
                    yum upgrade google-chrome-stable
                    google_version=`google-chrome --version`;
                    echo 'Google Chrome Version:' $google_version;
                    echo 'Currently LATEST_RELEASE:' $version;
                    dpkg -c tmp/bin/chromedriver
                    
                    ls -l tmp/bin/chromedriver
                    
                    '''
                    
                    // Check if the 'google' folder was created
                    if (sh(script: 'test -d tmp/bin/google', returnStatus: true) == 0) {
                        echo 'Folder "tmp/bin/chrome" created successfully.'
                    } else {
                        error 'Failed to create folder "tmp/bin/chrome".'
                    }
                    
                    PATH = "/tmp/bin:$PATH"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Install Dependencies and Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/sh

                    echo "This is the Path"
                    printenv
                    echo "cache path"
                    npm config get cache
                    echo "Clean cache"
                    npm cache clean --force
                    echo "Trying npm install"
                    npm i
                    chmod +x node_modules/.bin/mocha
                    npm run test
                '''
            }
        }
    }
    // Post-build actions, etc.
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

describe('Automation test', async function () {
  let driver;

  this.timeout(190000); // set a timeout 
  console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");
  before(async function () {
    console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");
    const loggingPrefs = new Preferences();
    loggingPrefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);
    const options = new chrome.Options();
    options.setLoggingPrefs({ performance: 'ALL' });
    options.addArguments("--incognito");
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable');
    const caps = Capabilities.chrome();
    caps.setLoggingPrefs(loggingPrefs);
    console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");
    const chromedriverPath = '/tmp/bin/chromedriver';
    process.env['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriverPath;

    driver = new Builder().withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
      .setChromeOptions(options)
      .build();
```

Comment: Hi John, can you please add some additional information? Like Dockerfiles, compose files, etc

Comment: Hello, i really appreciate the response. 
So currently the way i'm doing it(which might be incorrect) is using a docker image for nodejs in my pipeline script. Then im manually installing google chrome/chromedriver in the stage after. This doesnt work. I will add the code.

Comment: I've added the code, so basically what i tried was to download chrome and chromedriver manually and then try to locate them so i can set the binary. I was able to find the path for chrome but not for chromedriver. Is there a better solution to run this on jenkins? I was thinking making a custom image for nodejs and selenium but not sure how.

Comment: Have you tried [this project](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)? If I understand correctly, you're having problems with building a right image, so I guess that instead of using a plain `node` image (which could have less stuff than you might need) you could try something from Selenium.

Comment: Im trying this now, but what im confused on is that i want my automation to run virtually on a linux agent. How would i have the port information of said agent? and would i use that port in my code? Because looks like you need selenium grid to run automation remotely and i didnt know that

Comment: I was able to solve this issue but now im getting a different error saying: 
 WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
I will mark your answer as correct.

Anyone in the future, you need selenium grid and a selenium stand alone jar file to run automation on remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to set up this automation project with jenkins.
All you need is selenium grid and selenium jar file to execute automation on remote machines.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).